# Uploading a folder full of files to a specific folder in Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, python-2.7, amazon-s3, boto3

There have been a few other questions like this, but none seem to have answered my problem specifically. I have a folder full of files I want to upload to Amazon S3, and I have tried various different things, all leading to no upload. Here's the code I have now. It successfully creates the folder on S3, but doesn't upload.

```
import os
import boto3

s3_bucket = 'bucketname'
s3_bucket_region = 'us-east-1'
folder = 'FolderName'

key_name = folder + '/' 
s3_connect = boto3.client('s3', s3_bucket_region)
try:
    bucket = s3_connect.put_object(Bucket=s3_bucket, Key=key_name)
    print "Bucket:", bucket
except Exception as e:
    print "Bucket Error " , e

# upload File to S3
for filename in os.listdir(folder):

    file_key_name = folder + '/' + filename
    local_path = os.getcwd()
    local_name = local_path + '/' + key_name + filename
    upload = s3_connect.upload_file(local_name, s3_bucket, file_key_name)
```

I have tried a file_key_name of just something like 'FolderName/' as well as 'FolderName/FileName'. I thought at first the first argument (local_name) didn't need a full path, but a relative path would work, but neither a full or relative path works.

What am I missing? The docs are pretty woefully lacking in this department. Plus it doesn't throw an error, it just doesn't upload.

Comment: This might be useful https://techietweak.wordpress.com/2016/05/16/file-handling-in-aws-s3-with-python-boto-library/ in this line `k.key=fileName` you should put `k.key=FolderName/FileName` for it to be uploaded to the folder.

Comment: I came across that, but alas, that uses the boto library, and I'm using boto3.

Comment: My bad, have you tried with the 3 examples in the doc? They all call `boto3.resource` instead of `boto3.client`. This is the bucket one: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.upload_file This is the object one: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.upload_file Using client (not sure if the same client as yours): http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file

Comment: Have you considered simply using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/)? There is a `aws s3 sync` command that can copy a hierarchy of directories with one command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works perfectly fine for me, but you need to **remove the try/catch section that creates the folder** on Amazon S3.

Amazon S3 does not actually support folders. Rather, the `Key` of an object includes the full path (eg `images/foo.jpg`). Therefore, you don't need to create the folders before storing a file in them (since they do not exist!).

Your code will have difficulty with nested folders. You might consider using the `aws s3 sync` or `aws s3 cp` commands in the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) if you don't need it written in your own code.

Comment: That was it. Thanks! Luckily I don't need nested folders, just one. And it's part of a larger application, so it has to be in python.