# How to download all files from s3 bucket to local linux server while passing bucket and local folder value at runtime using python

Tags: linux, python-3.x, amazon-s3, subprocess

I am making script to download files form s3 bucket to local linux folder. To achieve that i have to use dynamic values for buckets and folders where we want to download stuff.

I know how to do with

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket /linux/local/folder --recursive --p alusta
```

But how to accept bucket value at runtime

```
dwn_cmd = "aws s3 cp s3://bucket/name/" + str(year_name) + '/' + str(month_name)

folder_path = "/local/linux/folder/" + folder_name

#subprocess.call(['aws','s3','cp',dwn_cmd,folder_path,'--recursive','--p', 'alusta'])
```

This is showing error that subprocess needs s3 bucket path and local folder path. I think it is not picking up the path. If i hard code the path it is working but not with this. How could I achieve my result

Comment: Sorry I have used hashtag.. Comment.. but it is not there

Comment: can someone help me here.. i am hell stuck in this..

Answer (score 0):

With

```
dwn_cmd = "aws s3 cp s3://bucket/name/" + "2019" + '/' + "June"
folder_path = "/local/linux/folder/" + "test"
```

You will be calling

```
subprocess.call(['aws','s3','cp',
 "aws s3 cp s3://bucket/name/2019/June",
 "/local/linux/folder/test",
 '--recursive', '--p', 'alusta']);
```

Delete the `aws s3 cp` parameters from `dwn_command`:

```
dwn_cmd = "s3://bucket/name/" + "2019" + '/' + "June"
```

Note: Do not use 
subprocess.call([dwn_cmd, folder_path,'--recursive','--p', 'alusta']) # wrong
The space between `aws` and `s3` will be considered as part of the command name, so it would look for the command in a subdirectory of the directory with 3 spaces `aws s3 cp s3:`.